# How to return the mongodb data received?

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

```
public static ArrayList<DBObject> retrieve(String dbName, String collectionName, String key, String value)
{
    ArrayList<DBObject> ar = new ArrayList();
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new 
    MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
    BasicDBObject Query = new BasicDBObject();
    Query.put(key, value);
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(Query);
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        LOGGER.info(cursor.next().toString());
        ar.add(cursor.next());
    }
    LOGGER.info(ar.toString());
    return(ar);

}
```

This is my class function that retrieves the data from the database. I require to return this data to another class. Is this the right method? If not, how should i do it?

Data example:

```
[
    {
    "id": "234567",
    "reportType": "Thyroid",
    "age": 21,
    "gender": "Female",
    "onThyroxine": false,
    "onAntiThyroideMed": false,
    "sick": false,
    "pregnant": false,
    "recentThryoidSurgery": false,
    "lithium": false,
    "goitre": false,
    "tumor": false,
    "hypopituitary": false,
    "i131Treatment": false,
    "fti": 11,
    "tbg": 123,
    "tt4": 23,
    "t3": 120,
    "t4U": 12,
    "tsh": 120
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to return all documents found as a result of the query, you can use the `toArray()` method of DBCursor.

Refer - http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html

Basically this -

```
public static ArrayList<DBObject> retrieve(String dbName, String collectionName, String key, String value) {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new 
    MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
    BasicDBObject Query = new BasicDBObject();
    Query.put(key, value);
    return collection.find(Query).toArray();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of this class in an another class where you need this data to be referred.

You can call `.retrieve()` method on the object of this class in the class where you need this data.

Answer (score 0):

Edited code:

```
public static List<DBObject> retrieve(String dbName, String collectionName, String key, String value)
{
    ArrayList<DBObject> ar = new ArrayList();
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new 
    MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
    BasicDBObject Query = new BasicDBObject();
    Query.put(key, value);
    //DBCursor cursor = collection.find(Query);
    List<DBObject> obj = collection.find(Query).limit(100).toArray();
    LOGGER.info(obj.toString());
    return(obj);   
}
```

In reference to Rishikesh's answer, here is the updated code. This works perfectly.